# Is there a vectorized way to do matrix multiplication-like operations in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix **A** of shape *m x n* and another smaller matrix **B** of shape *k x n*. I want to calculate the euclidean distance between the rows of A and B, generating a matrix **C** of shape *m x k*. I already have a function `dist(row1, row2)`. This is trivial using loops, but is there a vectorized way to do this in NumPy?

I believe what I want can be translated to a custom matrix multiplication-like operation (if I transpose B), and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55985900/custom-matrix-multiplication-with-numpy) seems to head in the same direction, but the best answer there rearrange the operations in order to achieve vectorization (I want to use my separate function `dist(row1, row2)`). The second answer uses a separate function, but it also use loops.

Comment: Hi, can you please include the current code you're using with few example rows for each matrix?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NumPy Broadcasting: Calculating sum of squared differences between two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36241608/numpy-broadcasting-calculating-sum-of-squared-differences-between-two-arrays)

Comment: @Guglie: thanks, but I was looking for a more readable solution. `einsum` looks like black magic. If that's the only solution, I rather use loops in my case.

Comment: I guess you want to do something like that? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42994680/4045774

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below which may help? If `A` is shape `mxn` and `B` is shape `kxn`, `C` should be shape `mxk`

```
C = np.linalg.norm([A[:,None,:]-B],axis=-1)
```

Comment: Do you mind to explain this? It doesn't seem very obvious.

Comment: For euclidean distance between your rows, you need difference between each row of `A` &each row of `B` but since they have different shapes in 1st dimension (rows) but same in the trailing dim. (`n` columns), you make them [compatible](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) by making a dimension `1` using the `None` keyword. After the difference you get a `mxkxn` array, and using  `np.linalg.norm` on last axis (-1) of shape `n` you get the euclidean distance. I suggest give it a try on your data or provide a sample input & desired output in your post to check ?